# Setter is not setting value to java object

Tags: java, android, firebase, oop, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set key (firebase key) to my java object TaskModel. But after using setter when I'm trying to retrieve data using getter. It is returning null.

Database Structure

[image]

```
for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                taskModel.setTaskID(dataSnapshot1.getKey());
                taskModel = dataSnapshot1.getValue(TaskModel.class);
                Log.d("myadaptor", taskModel.getTaskID());
                list.add(taskModel);
            }
```

Please help me set key to my object!

**TaskModel.java**

```
public class TaskModel {
    private String taskTitle;
    private String dueDate;
    private String taskDescription;
    private String taskID;

    public String getTaskID() {
        return taskID;
    }

    public void setTaskID(String taskID) {
        this.taskID = taskID;
    }

    public String getTaskTitle() {
        return taskTitle;
    }

    public void setTaskTitle(String taskTitle) {
        this.taskTitle = taskTitle;
    }

    public String getDueDate() {
        return dueDate;
    }

    public void setDueDate(String dueDate) {
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }

    public String getTaskDescription() {
        return taskDescription;
    }

    public void setTaskDescription(String taskDescription) {
        this.taskDescription = taskDescription;
    }

    public TaskModel(String taskTitle, String dueDate, String taskDescription) {
        this.taskTitle = taskTitle;
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
        this.taskDescription = taskDescription;
    }

    public TaskModel(){

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post database structure.

Comment: comment on this line taskModel = dataSnapshot1.getValue(TaskModel.class); and try again

Comment: @hamidkeyhani but that line is setting value like dueDate, title,description. I want to set the key as task ID in order to delete that particular node using taskID.

Comment: @Ashish done, I posted the picture of database structure

Comment: can you check if the `dataSnapshot` is exist or not?

Comment: @Ticherhaz yes it does exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in your old code, you are assigning ID to taskModel, after that you initializing taskModel as new object from dataSnapShot. And in dataSnapShot you have `null` as id. SO it is like overridden of id:

```
            taskModel.setTaskID(dataSnapshot1.getKey());
            taskModel = dataSnapshot1.getValue(TaskModel.class);
```

Update the position of line:

```
        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            taskModel = dataSnapshot1.getValue(TaskModel.class);
            taskModel.setTaskID(dataSnapshot1.getKey());
            Log.d("myadaptor", taskModel.getTaskID());
            list.add(taskModel);
        }
```